# Why does adding a "pending" break my Scala test?

Tags: scala, scalatest

The commented line below breaks my testing

```
import org.scalatest.WordSpec

class LSESuite extends WordSpec {

  "An LSE market" should {
    "round values" in  {
      val lse = new LSE {
      }
      assert(lse.getMarketName === "LSE")
      //"min tick size" is (pending)
    }
  }
}
```

I receive the following error "An it clause may not appear inside another it clause" but I'm not sure how to interpret. Edit stack trace:

```
org.scalatest.TestRegistrationClosedException: An it clause may not appear inside another it clause.
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.registerTest(Engine.scala:406)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpec$class.org$scalatest$WordSpec$$registerTestToRun(WordSpec.scala:1643)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpec$WordSpecStringWrapper.is(WordSpec.scala:1823)


    at org.scalatest.WordSpec$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(WordSpec.scala:2232)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpec$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(WordSpec.scala:2232)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch$1.apply(Engine.scala:226)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch$1.apply(Engine.scala:215)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:215)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch$1.apply(Engine.scala:231)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch$1.apply(Engine.scala:215)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:215)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:282)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpec$class.runTests(WordSpec.scala:2232)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:2286)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpec$$anonfun$run$1.apply(WordSpec.scala:2279)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpec$$anonfun$run$1.apply(WordSpec.scala:2279)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:318)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpec$class.run(WordSpec.scala:2279)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:59)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:1517)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:1514)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1514)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:584)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:583)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1558)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:582)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:485)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTest15Scala28Runner.main(ScalaTest15Scala28Runner.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Can also attach the failure message? I am not able to reproduce it with the given code snippet.

Comment: Just checking did you remove the comment from the code?

Comment: How are you running the test?

Answer (score 0):

Your 'pending' seems to be in an odd location. So you might see the same problem as I saw here: http://groups.google.com/group/scalatest-users/browse_thread/thread/177bbc520edc8fbd